# Where is the implantation of annotation in springframework?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Sorry if this is a silly question.

I know how to use `@Component` `@Autowired` in projects based on springframework, but I could not find the implementations of those annotation, simply searching in springframework code repository gives me so much thing.

I want to find the work behind those annotation that springframework did for me.

thank you.